# Customizable Flash Player?

Tags: flash, audiovideoplayback

I am looking for a customizable flash player which can do the following:

1. Be given a playlist and will play the videos in succession
2. Can support ads at the bottom (like what we see on YouTube player)
3. Allows for easy skinning
4. Preferably free or cost effective

Answer (score 0):

You would probably benefit most from [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org). No-attribution version is $99.